# parse JSON Tree in java

Tags: java, json

I could not find out how to traverse a JSON-tree (nested structure) and decide on the keys of the elements what to expect next and traverse from node to node. Like this (pseudocode):

```
int  traverse(node) {
  if (node.key == ADD) {
    int res = 0; 
    for (child:node.children)  
     res = res + traverse(child);
  }
  if (node.key == "ADD") {
  int res = 0; 
  for (child:node.children) 
    res = res + traverse(children);
  }
  if (node.key == "MULT") {
    int res = 0; 
    for (child:node.children) 
      res = res * traverse(children);
  }

  if (node.key == "INT")  
    return node.value;
}
```

The json-string to parse could be like this:

```
 {"ADD":[{"INT":"1"},{"INT":"3"},{"INT":"4"}]}
```

or this:

```
 {"ADD":[{"INT":"1"},{"INT":"3"},{"ADD":[{"INT":"5"},{"INT":"6"}]},      
 {"INT":"4"}]}
```

How could I use JSON-Object or JSON-Arrays and 
inside the objects access the key and value variables to traverse through this tree recursively?

EDITED:
After all the comments I try to put this as first running example
(still looks a little uneasy to me, but it works):

```
public static int evaluate(javax.json.JsonObject node) {

  Set<?> keySet = node.keySet(); 
  Iterator<?> i = keySet.iterator(); 
  if (i.hasNext()) { 
    String key = i.next().toString();
        System.out.println("key: " + key);      
    if (key.equals("ADD"))  {
      JsonArray ja = node.getJsonArray("ADD");
      int  res = 0;
      for (JsonValue jvx: ja) {
    if (jvx.getValueType().toString().equals("OBJECT"))  {
      res = res + evaluate((JsonObject)jvx);        
            }  else{
      System.err.println("jvx should not be a " + jvx.getValueType().toString() + " here");
        }
      }
      return res;
    }
    if (key.equals("MULT"))  {
      JsonArray ja = node.getJsonArray("MULT");
      int  res = 1;
      for (JsonValue jvx: ja) {
    if (jvx.getValueType().toString().equals("OBJECT"))  {
      res = res * evaluate((JsonObject)jvx);        
            }  else{
      System.err.println("jvx should not be a " + jvx.getValueType().toString() + " here");
        }
      }
      return res;
    }
    if (key.equals("INT")) {
      String intStr = node.getString("INT");
      System.out.println ("found int = " + intStr);
      return Integer.parseInt(intStr);

        }
      }
      return 0; 
}


public static  void readJSON() {
  String jsonText =  "{\"ADD\":[{\"INT\":\"1\"},{\"INT\":\"3\"},{\"ADD\":[{\"INT\":\"5\"},{\"INT\":\"6\"}]},{\"INT\":\"4\"}]}";
      JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonText));
      JsonObject obj = reader.readObject();
      reader.close();
      int res = evaluate(obj);
  System.out.println("res: " + res); 
}
```

Comment: java's built in JSON libraries are the quickets way to do so, but in my experience GSON is the best library for parsing a JSON into a POJO painlessly.

Comment: Don't do `node.key == "MULT"`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: @BartKiers The OP said it was pseudo-code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your evaluating pseudocode is OK (just pay attention to the initial value when multiplying!). To adapt it to the `javax.json` hierarchy, you should code your evaluating method like this:

`int evaluate(javax.json.JsonObject node)`:

- Get each on of the admitted keys (`ADD`, `MULT`, `INT`, etc) through `node.getJsonObject(key)`: In case it returns null, check the next admitted key, and stop at the first you find.
- On each operation, a proper logic must be coded:

  1. In case the key is a constant value (`INT`), return its value immediately.
  2. In case the key is an operation, check the value's type (through `node.getValueType()`): If it is a single value, return it as is. If it is an array, iterate through its elements and call `evaluate` for each one of them, and perform the proper operation with the returned value (adding, multiplying, etc). Last, return the computation's result.

### After your first edit

Your first real approach looks OK; I'd just suggest you some improvements to make the code more readable:

1. Use an *enhanced for*.
2. Replace the if-else chanin by a `switch`.
3. Replace each case by a call to a private method.

   ```
   int result;
   Set<String> keySet = node.keySet(); 
   for (String key : keySet)
   {
       switch (key)
       {
           case "ADD":
               result=evaluateAdd(node.getJsonArray("ADD"));
               break;
           case "MULT":
               result=evaluateMult(node.getJsonArray("ADD"));
               break;
           case "INT":
               result=node.getInt("INT");
               break;
            ...
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: String testJSON = 
"{\"ADD\":[{\"INT\":\"1\"},{\"INT\":\"3\"},{\"ADD\":[{\"INT\":\"5\"},{\"INT
     \":\"6\"}]},{\"INT\":\"4\"}]}";
getValueType for this is OBJECT. I would have expected ADD or ARRAY.

Comment: @Mike75 No, you are wrong: You are expecting that `node` is an OBJECT which returns `node.getJsonArray("ADD")!=null`.

Comment: you sayd "check the value's type (through node.getValueType()".
What for should I test, to find out if it is a single value?

Comment: For clarification let me ask the other way around:
I would like to get the first key ("ADD") from the String testJSON and
decide what to do next on this key.
How can I get the key from the JSONObject?

Comment: there is a method KeySet(), but it seems to be a map,
I would need it ordered to really get the first key (or in general: 
an ordered list of the keys).
So I think get("ADD") could be too ambigious in  some more general cases.

Comment: You can get the "ADD" value executing `JSonObject nodeAdd=getJsonObject("ADD")`. Then check if it is null, otherwise check which type it is: `nodeAdd.getValueType()`, which shall return `NUMBER` or `ARRAY`.

Comment: O.k. If I don't want to retrieve ("ADD") directly, I tried this:
`Set<?> s =  node.keySet();
   Iterator<?> i = s.iterator();
   String key = i.next().toString();`
But this seems a little uneasy to me.

Comment: I edited the question and pasted a running example of the code.

Answer (score 0):

JSON [{
"name": "com",
"children": [
{
"name": "project",
"children": [
{
"name": "server"
},
{
"name": "client",
"children": [
{
"name": "util"
}
]
}
]
}
]
}]

Try this:

```
public static JSONArray getNames(JSONArray inputArray, JSONArray outputArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject inputObject = inputArray.getJSONObject(i);

        JSONObject outputObject = new JSONObject();
        outputObject.put("name", inputObject.getString("name"));
        outputArray.put(outputObject);

        if (inputObject.has("children")) {
            JSONArray children = inputObject.getJSONArray("children");
            getNames(children, outputArray);
        }
    }

    return outputArray;
}
```